# App crashes on Socket connect

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to make a connection with a python server I made but everytime I press the button my app crashes.

Here is my code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String ip = "<IP>";
            int port = <PORT>;

            try {
                Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
                System.out.println("connected!");
                s.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    });
}
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I really don't understand what went wrong

Comment: please add your error logs

Comment: move socket connection to another thread, you can not perform networking on main thread. in future - post your logcat logs. also, i'm not sure you have no other problems

Comment: You have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Clearly visible in the logcat! Please look for it.

Comment: hava a look a AsynchTask, very helpful!

Comment: you can accept the answer if it is helpful..

Answer (score 4):

You are doing network on main UI thread which is not allowed. So use async Task and do this task in background thread. For that, create a class (for ex. `background.java` )and use Async task in it.

```
 Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

         background bg = new background();
         bg.execute();

    }
});
```

and in your background class:

```
public class background extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

         String ip = "<IP>";
        int port = <PORT>;

        try {
            Socket s = new Socket(ip, port);
            System.out.println("connected!");
            s.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps :)